# Convert a transformation matrix from world-space to camera-space using Eigen

Tags: c++, matrix, transformation

I have a transformation matrix, in world space. I need to convert it to local(camera) space.

I have done the reverse of this (Local - to - world) using:

```
Eigen::Matrix3f R0; //rotation matrix
Eigen::Vector3f T0; // xyz translation values
Eigen::Vector3f C0; //result

R0.transposeInPlace();  //invert rotation matrix

C0 = -R0 * T0;   //return world-space coordinate
```

Can I simply run this exact same thing to invert it the other way? Or is it a different equation?

Answer (score 1):

Aha, to solve the reverse, i can simply use:

```
Eigen::Matrix3f R0; //rotation matrix in world space
Eigen::Vector3f T0; // xyz translation values in world space
Eigen::Vector3f C0; //result

R0.transposeInPlace(); 
C0 = -R0 * T0;
```

So it is the same equation.